# Jquery UI tabs slow on tab change with too much data

Tags: jquery, performance, tabs, rendering, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page wrote in C#, using update panel and inside this panel there is some tabs with bound data from sql server.

All data is bound on page load, then when change the selected tab, it is very very slow to show the new table (bound on init page load, not on tab change).

There is any way to let it less slow? I think the time is wasted on rendering, considering the data is not bound again.

Comment: I would consider including less data. If you have enough data being displayed to make a tab change slow, then you are displaying too much data at once.

Comment: Try to use the pagination option to reduce the number of rendered items

Comment: I'm already using pagination and it still works slowly

Comment: Dom, i think the code is not necessary, cause i just bind 7 gridviews (not all with lot of data) inside a function and create the tabs on init function to separate the gridviews.